# Cassandra c++ driver "undefined reference" error

Tags: c++, cassandra, g++

So I followed the Ubuntu instructions on the Datastax website to build the c++ driver (http://datastax.github.io/cpp-driver/topics/building/).

sudo apt-add-repository ppa:linuxjedi/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install g++ make cmake libuv-dev libssl-dev

git clone https://github.com/datastax/cpp-driver.git

mkdir cpp-driver/build

cd cpp-driver/build

cmake ..

make

When I try to compile using g++ I get the following error messages:
test.cpp:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to `cass_cluster_new'
test.cpp:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to`cass_session_new'
test.cpp:(.text+0x2f): undefined reference to `cass_cluster_set_contact_points'
test.cpp:(.text+0x42): undefined reference to`cass_session_connect'
test.cpp:(.text+0x52): undefined reference to `cass_future_error_code'
test.cpp:(.text+0x76): undefined reference to`cass_statement_new'
test.cpp:(.text+0x8d): undefined reference to `cass_session_execute'
test.cpp:(.text+0x9d): undefined reference to`cass_future_error_code'
test.cpp:(.text+0xb6): undefined reference to `cass_future_get_result'
test.cpp:(.text+0xc6): undefined reference to`cass_iterator_from_result'
test.cpp:(.text+0xd8): undefined reference to `cass_iterator_get_row'
test.cpp:(.text+0xed): undefined reference to`cass_row_get_column_by_name'
test.cpp:(.text+0x108): undefined reference to `cass_value_get_string'
test.cpp:(.text+0x12d): undefined reference to`cass_iterator_next'
test.cpp:(.text+0x142): undefined reference to `cass_result_free'
test.cpp:(.text+0x14e): undefined reference to`cass_iterator_free'
test.cpp:(.text+0x167): undefined reference to `cass_future_error_message'
test.cpp:(.text+0x196): undefined reference to`cass_statement_free'
test.cpp:(.text+0x1a2): undefined reference to `cass_future_free'
test.cpp:(.text+0x1ae): undefined reference to`cass_session_close'
test.cpp:(.text+0x1be): undefined reference to `cass_future_wait'
test.cpp:(.text+0x1ca): undefined reference to`cass_future_free'
test.cpp:(.text+0x1e3): undefined reference to `cass_future_error_message'
test.cpp:(.text+0x212): undefined reference to`cass_future_free'
test.cpp:(.text+0x21e): undefined reference to `cass_cluster_free'
test.cpp:(.text+0x22a): undefined reference to`cass_session_free'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

What am I missing when trying to compile: g++ test.cpp

Thank you.

Comment: You're missing the library dependencies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to actually link to the previously build cassandra driver.

```
g++ test.cpp -Lcpp-build/build -lcassandra
```

-L tells g++ where it searches for libraries

-l links the library

Comment: Thank you that did the trick. Its been over ten years since I've touched C++.

Comment: One other question. since I compiled the driver instead of using a binary I get an error when I do not specify the full path to the library. "test.cpp:1:23: fatal error: cassandra.h: No such file or directory
 #include <cassandra.h>". Do you know how I can change it such that I can type #include <cassandra.h> instead of #include </path_to_library/cassandra.h> and have the program compile?

Comment: You can specify additional include directories with the -I (uppercase i) flag like so:
    g++ ... -Icpp-driver/include